# how is the search mail button implemented?

Tags: javascript, css, gmail

I am using Firebug, I just saw tha it is a div with css, but I dont get it how they did it?

```
<div id=":ri" class="J-Zh-I J-J5-Ji L3 J-Zh-I-Js-Zq" tabindex="0" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Search Mail</div>
```

I am trying to make something similar but I am just a beginner,I want that effect of the button but I don't get it how they did it? even I don't understand the css, I just copy this but no effect

```
.num1 {
-moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F5F5F5, #F1F1F1) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #666666;
    cursor: default;
    font: 75% arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 3px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.num2{
 display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.num3{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    margin-left: 0 !important;


}
```

[image]

Comment: You just copied it and it had no effect? It didn't go to your clipboard? did you paste it somewhere? Did you open that file with a browser? what browser? what showed up? What were you expecting? etc

Comment: I want all the effect of the button

Comment: That css is just for styling, the functionality is defined elsewhere.

Comment: oh I see but how to make that div into a button?, I am searching about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here just the CSSed div: http://jsfiddle.net/bmWGY/1/

You'll need much more if you want to do something with this div.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail uses JavaScript to detect the `click` event on the `div`. In addition, classes are dynamically added/removed to give the "button" the correct styles.

It is much easier to style a `div` element correctly than to try to style `input` and `button` elements for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: how that classes are dynamically added/removed can you explain please?

Comment: @George: By setting the `className` property of the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a simple div with a javascript `onclick` function attached. If using jQuery or some other framework, the "action" can be defined elsewhere using the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (for jQuery) functions. See the examples provided in the preceding two links to see this in action.

Comment: but It has no that method Firebug says <div id=":ri" class="J-Zh-I J-J5-Ji L3 J-Zh-I-Js-Zq" tabindex="0" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Search Mail</div>

Comment: That's fine, they may be using a secondary script to bind an action to the `div`. See the code on the `click` and `bind` pages for examples of how that works.